# Xcode with Numerous Targets Slowing Down

Tags: xcode, indexing, target

I have an Xcode Project I'm working with for a client.  The project has around 78 targets in order to facilitate a main app and a split-off of around 77 "sub-apps" that display varying information from a web server (using the main app as a kind of template).

Also, this isn't exactly a small app.  There are around 70-80 classes, 5 storyboards and probably 30-40 different screens.

I'm having a problem with Xcode seriously bogging down.  There are two problem areas:

- Indexing takes forever.  Xcode is indexing each and every single target separately.
- In Storyboard: `Refresh all Views` takes around 30 minutes as Xcode builds each target separately before it actually gets around to refreshing the storyboard's views... and I have to do this 5 times, once for each storyboard.

What I need is a way to prevent Xcode from indexing anything except the "Main" target.  Likewise the `Refresh all Views` option.

Any ideas?  Is there perhaps a better way to structure the project?

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible answer.  I'm not entirely sure yet how well it's going to work in the long run.  *Note:* I use cocoa pods, so I've gotta deal with a workspace, which in the end may cause me the most problems.

1. I copied both my `.xcworkspace` and `xcodeproj` files and renamed them.
2. In the copied workspace file, I removed the main Xcode project and inserted the copied project.
3. In the copied project, I removed the main, test and documentation targets mostly to avoid confusion. The only targets left are the 77.
4. In the main workspace, I removed all 77 of the 'sub-app' targets.  It took about Xcode 20 minutes to do this.  Seriously comical.

I will do all of my development in the main workspace.  In the copied workspace I will only build the sub-apps as needed.

One downside is that I'll need to add any new files to both projects, but I don't think this will be too onerous.

Probably the biggest problem will be when I need to add/update a cocoa pod. I'll cross that bridge when I get there.

Comment: Yeah I have real beef trying to organize code into self-sufficient and self-standing, testable apps without having to wait forever to set up each target (with Cocoapods). It's a real challenge.